# how do I use `Observable.bindCallback()` with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've got a google maps direction service I'm trying to convert to an Observable pattern. Here is the example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple:

```
  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried the following:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
...
  // the callback version works
  getRoute (route: any) {
    const defaults = { 'travelMode': 'WALKING' };
    route = Object.assign(defaults, route);
    this._directionsService.route(
      route
      , (res:any, status:string) => {
          if (status == 'OK')
            this.displayRoute(res);
          else
            this.handleError(res)
       })
  }

  // the Observable version doesn't get past typescript
  getRoute$ (route: any) {
    const defaults = { 'travelMode': 'WALKING' };
    route = Object.assign(defaults, route);
    let route$ = Observable.bindCallback(
      this._directionsService.route
      , (res, status)=>{res, status}
    );
    // TS says, "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
    route$( route ).subscribe(
      (resp:any)=>{
        // also, how do I throw an error from the selector func?
        if (resp.status == 'OK')
          this.displayRoute(resp.res);
        else
          this.handleError(resp.res)
      }
    )
  }
```

Why is typescript rejecting this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just dealt with the same error while trying to use bindCallback. I got around it by explicitly specifying the type of the var pointing to the result of bindCallback. I just used "any". In your case, try

```
let route$ : any = Observable.bindCallback(...)
```

This doesn't explain *why* Typescript rejects it though. I'd guess it's because the type definitions for the result of bindCallback are parameterized (i.e., they're generically typed). Look at BoundCallbackObservable.d.ts to see what I mean. Notice the multiple parameterized definitions for all those overloaded "create" methods (one of which is ultimately what gets invoked).

Answer (score 1):

In rxjs 5 you can fix this by fulfilling the following type signature.

```
static create<T, R>(callbackFunc: (v1: T, callback: (result: R) => any) => any, selector?: void, scheduler?: IScheduler): (v1: T) => Observable<R>;
```

Notice that it takes two types in order to return a callback with one parameter type `T` that returns `Observable<R>`.

### Usage

```
type routeType = String

interface returnType = {
  res: any
  status: any
}

let route$: any = Observable.bindCallback<routeType, observableType>(this._directionsService.route, (res, status)=>{res, status})
```

Now the type of `route$` is `(v1: routeType) => Observable<observableType>`

Comment: I think you meant:

let route$: any = Observable.bindCallback<routeType, returnType>(this._directionsService.route, (res, status)=>{res, status})

not "observableType", right?